Is there a need to throttle spring boot actuator health endpoint
I have created a spring boot app having various endpoints secured and throttling is enabled on them like if more then certain calls will come in a minute it will give 429.
My /health endpoint doesn't need any auth or apikey. So a person or attacker can call this api numerous times, will it impact my overall application performance making it slow?
I have tried reading the documentation but unable to find any checks against the above concern. Please let me know if any throttling or any check required here.
I am using spring boot 3

Every request that comes in uses a thread and memory, the more threads involved (or even if there are no more threads) will thus impact your application. So yes if they are publicly accessible you probably want to protect/limit those, however you might also want to question yourself and do they really need to be exposed to the public or just internally?


You can add security check on /health endpoint


add spring-boot-starter-security dependency
You can find default config in org.springframework.boot.actuate.autoconfigure.security.servlet.ManagementWebSecurityAutoConfiguration. It check every endpoint besides /info and /health, so you need exclude it since you need security check on /health.

@SpringBootApplication(exclude = { 
    SecurityAutoConfiguration.class, 
    ManagementWebSecurityAutoConfiguration.class 
})


Then add your personal security check in security config, such as limit only admin user can check /health

http.requestMatcher(EndpointRequest.to("/health"))
  .authorizeRequests((requests) -> requests.anyRequest().hasRole("ADMIN"));



or just disable it by management.endpoint.health.enabled=false if you don't need it.

